# Look Up Table in SQL

Tags: sql

I basically have a table A with 30 million records and I want to add a column entitled "TYPE" to the table. I have a look up table B that maps a code to a color. I want to iterate through table A and compare the code in TABLE A to the code in TABLE B and then add the color to the TYPE column in table A. Is this possible? What would be the best approach to this problem? The codes in table B don't match perfectly with the actual codes in table A.

Comment: What DBMS and why are you adding this to the table if it is already available through a join?

Comment: An appropriate, single update statement. No iteration. (Best syntax for the update statement will vary by particular database product.)

Comment: The problem is that the codes don't match perfectly. The first couple of digits match, and are enough to list the type. So I would need if statements for each condition. For example, the actual code might be 434344 but in the look up table, you might only see 43-> GREEN

Comment: @lord12 - Then its hardly a "look up" table

Comment: I am using Netezza and SquirrelSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hard to say without seeing the schema or knowing the DBMS but, if it's always a the first 2 digits of the code used to look up the color, why not

```
UPDATE table_a SET type = SUBSTR(code, 2)
```

and do a JOIN normally

you could do a join like

```
JOIN table_b ON table_b.id = SUBSTR(table_a.code,2)
```

but that would hardly be performant.

Answer (score 0):

Give or take issues with size of transaction, isn't it a simple ALTER TABLE to add the column and an UPDATE to fix it?

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD (Type VARCHAR(10));

UPDATE TableA
   SET Type = ((SELECT Colour FROM TableB WHERE TableA.Type = TableB.Type));
```

The only tricky bit might be the double parentheses; they're needed in some DBMS and may not be needed in others (single parentheses may be sufficient).  You may also be able to use a UPDATE with a JOIN; the syntax isn't entirely standard there, either.

Note that this mapping relies on a change of NULL to NULL being a no-op.  If you have values in some rows but not all of those rows match an entry in TableB, then you need to be careful with an full-table UPDATE like that.  It will set the Type for any rows in TableA for which there is no match in TableB to NULL.  If that wasn't what you needed, you'd either use an UPDATE with JOIN or you'd write:

```
UPDATE TableA
   SET Type = ((SELECT Colour FROM TableB WHERE TableA.Type = TableB.Type));
 WHERE Type IN (SELECT Colour FROM TableB WHERE TableA.Type = TableB.Type);
```

In the current case, where the column is newly added and therefore contains NULL anyway, there is no harm done omitting the WHERE clause on the UPDATE itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the update just by looking at the first  characters of the code in table B, as in the following statement:

```
update table_a
    set table_a.type = table_b.type
    from table_b
    where table_b.code = substr(table_a.code, 1, length(table_b.code))
```

This may be a bit slow, since you cannot use any indexes to speed it up.  However, if table_b is small, then the performance may be acceptable.